# What is this string Chrome appends to the label in MediaDeviceInfo?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

In the device list returned by [enumerateDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices), instead of `FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)`, Chrome labels this device `FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in) (05ac:1254)` for me. It does the same for *some* other microphones and *some* other speakers but not all.

FireFox does not appear to do this at all, which is why I assume this is a Chrome-specific behavior.

I can't find any information about what this string means and why it's appended. Can anyone fill me in?